# Monitoring Dask memory usage without Dashboard

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am quite new to using Dask and have been trying out the distributed functionality on a moderately large workload. My basic setup and some additional context is as follows:

- I am running a cluster of 8 workers, 8 threads per worker and 60GB memory per worker
- I am reading in moderately large files (anywhere from 10-20 parquet files, each of size 60-70GB and each of which is partitioned into roughly 300 partitions)
- My scripts do basic filtering, aggregation and merging, and I am mostly using the `dask.dataframe` functions. I `persist` and `compute` final values regularly
- I am using Jupyter Notebooks to run my scripts

My problems and follow up questions are:

1. I'm having some issues when it comes to memory utilisation (I consistently get `KilledWorker` warnings for using too much memory and want to understand why). I get these errors even when reading in only a single 60GB file, despite the fact that (on paper) I should have more than enough memory to cope with these files. Unfortunately my organisation doesn't allow the Dask dashboard through their firewall so I have to use some other means to monitor memory/cpu usage. What other tools could I use to do this that run natively in Jupyter (included in Dask or otherwise but preferably without the need for additional packages, other than those inlcuded with standard Python installations, to be installed)?
2. Whilst the files should comfortably fit in memory, they have quite large dimensions (around 60 million rows and 1000+ columns) and often take 1+ hours to read in using the Dask `dd.read_parquet` function. In the past I have struggled when loading files this large into Python, particularly with Pandas, but thought that Dask would be able to handle such files. Additionally, I have another process that reads in files (of roughly the same size) that have fewer columns (only around 20) but more rows (400+ million) and these take less than half the time to read in. Whilst this probably ties in closely with the memory utilisation question I've asked above, I want to understand the most efficient way to read in files that have a large number of columns. Is there a way to divide them up into smaller chunks (say 50 columns per chunk) that could then be merged together that would be much quicker than reading in files with 1000 columns?
3. Once read in, performing any operations on these files is extremely time consuming and often fails. Below is a section of code that I have yet to get running correctly, despite leaving it to run for 6+ hours (and having it fail because of workers being killed). Is there a way to make this code more efficient? For reference "large_file" is the 60GB file with 1000+ columns and "small file" is a smaller file, around 300MB with 30 columns:

```
# 60GB file read in
ddf_large_file = dd.read_parquet("path/to/large_file")

# increment update_month, format yyyy-mm, to next month and reformat
ddf_large_file["update_month"] = (dd.to_datetime(ddf_large_file["update_month"].str[0:4] + ddf_large_file["update_month"].str[-2] + '01') + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

ddf_large_file["update_month"] = ddf_large_file["update_month"].str[0:4] + "-" + ddf_large_file["update_month"].str[4:6]

ddf_large_file = client.persist(ddf_large_file)

# create and set new index
ddf_large_file["index_col"] = ddf_large_file["match_key"] + ddf_large_file["update_month"]

ddf_large_file = ddf_large_file.set_index("index_col")

ddf_large_file = ddf_large_file.persist()

# merge ddf_large_file to ddf_small_file (around 300MB) on index and drop duplicates.
# NOTE: I have not managed to get beyond this stage as the workers are killed due to memory usage
ddf_large_file = ddf_large_file.merge(ddf_small_file,
                                      how='inner',
                                      left_index=True,
                                      right_index=True)

ddf_large_file = ddf_large_file.drop_duplicates(subset=["match_key", "update_month", "other_cols"]).reset_index(drop=True)

ddf_large_file = client.persist(ddf_large_file)
ddf_large_file = ddf_large_file.compute()

# change data to list for speed
list_large_file = []
list_large_file.extend(ddf_large_file.values.tolist())

cols = ddf_large_file.columns.to_list()

Final_Data = pd.DataFrame(list_large_file, columns=cols)
Final_Data = Final_Data.drop_duplicates(subset=["match_key", "other_cols"])

Final_Data = Final_Data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Note that this is just one file being read in rather than 10-20 as I want to concentrate on getting the intermediate steps working.

TLDR; How can I assess memory/cpu usage in Dask without the Dask dashboard? Why do my 60GB files crash when run through my code, even though on paper I have 400+GB of RAM available so should be able to process them? Is there a way to make the above code more efficient for working with wide (1000+ columns) files, e.g. break into 50 column chunks?

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Comment: You might get a better response if you split this up into three questions, as they are fairly separate. Some quick tips. 1. `persists` will trigger the computation, `compute` will trigger the computation and send it to the client (materialize it as `pd.DataFrame`). After both of those, you have the whole dataframe in memory. 2. 60GB parquet may be much bigger in memory both due to compression and the inner workings of Pandas and Dask, so even 400gb might not be enough for a 60gb parquet.

Comment: 3. You might consider writing `to_parquet` instead of persisting before the problematic steps, sometimes that can help with critical steps in the computation. 4. You might be interested in [performance reports](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/diagnosing-performance.html#performance-reports)

Comment: @Dahn Thanks for the reply. The performance reports sound like a good shout and I'll try out what you have recommended regarding the writing of data to parquet and see if that makes a difference

Comment: My guess is that `set_index` is slowing you down and taking up memory. This is because Dask does an internal compute operation when you use `set-index`. :/